# Moving a large table to another filegroup

Tags: sql-server

I have a 30 million row table, which is causing performance issues. I thought of moving it to a new `filegroup` for better performance.

My questions are:

This table has many `foreign key` references. If I just move the clustered index to another `filegroup`, will it still work right? Or do I also need to move the references to the new `filegroup`?

How about leaving the `nonclustered` indexes on the old `filegroup`?

Please suggest on my approach and my question.

Comment: You might just want to but the tables on a SSD (500-600mb/s) or M.2 SSD which can achieve 2gb or more per second.

Comment: A different filegroup will only make an improvement if the maps to different disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes your Foreign Key constraints (References) will work once you move the clustered index to a different filegroup.
2. You can leave the non-clustered indexes in the old file group (in my personal opinion it has some advantage to have clustered and non clustered index  in different file group especially if the underlying disks are different and write heavy workload)
3. Remember when you create a non-clustered index by default it goes to the same file group where your clustered index is. If you want non-clustered indexes in a separate file group you need to explicitly mention that. [Here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2013/03/12/filegroups-and-non-clustered-indexes.aspx) is a good example of this.